# OpenCV set pixels outside ROI as the nearest pixel value inside the ROI

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an image with a non-rectangular ROI, defined by a binary mask image.

In OpenCV, how can I set the pixels OUTSIDE my ROI as the nearest pixel value INSIDE the ROI? Something similar to what is in `cv::BORDER_REPLICATE`, or something similar to what is done in `cv::warp`

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [**`cv::inpaint()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/photo/doc/inpainting.html) by restoring the selected region region in an image using the region neighborhood.

In your case, that will be something like:

```
cv::inpaint(mat_input, 255 - roi, mat_output, inpaint_radius, cv::INPAINT_NS);
```